# Unable to modify mobilenet model for 2 class classification

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, mobilenet

I have the following mobilenet code, trying to customise the model and removing a block of layer and loading pretrained weights accordingly.

```
BASE_WEIGHT_PATH = ('https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/'
                    'keras-applications/mobilenet_v2/')
layers = None
@keras_export('keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.MobileNetV2',
              'keras.applications.MobileNetV2')
def MobileNetV2_15(input_shape=None,
                alpha=1.0,
                include_top=True,
                weights='imagenet',
                input_tensor=None,
                pooling=None,
                classes=1000,
                classifier_activation='softmax',
                **kwargs):
  global layers
  if 'layers' in kwargs:
    layers = kwargs.pop('layers')
  else:
    layers = VersionAwareLayers()
  if kwargs:
    raise ValueError('Unknown argument(s): %s' % (kwargs,))
  if not (weights in {'imagenet', None} or file_io.file_exists_v2(weights)):
    raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                     '`None` (random initialization), `imagenet` '
                     '(pre-training on ImageNet), '
                     'or the path to the weights file to be loaded.')

  if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
    raise ValueError('If using `weights` as `"imagenet"` with `include_top` '
                     'as true, `classes` should be 1000')

  # Determine proper input shape and default size.
  # If both input_shape and input_tensor are used, they should match
  if input_shape is not None and input_tensor is not None:
    try:
      is_input_t_tensor = backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor)
    except ValueError:
      try:
        is_input_t_tensor = backend.is_keras_tensor(
            layer_utils.get_source_inputs(input_tensor))
      except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('input_tensor: ', input_tensor,
                         'is not type input_tensor')
    if is_input_t_tensor:
      if backend.image_data_format == 'channels_first':
        if backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[1] != input_shape[1]:
          raise ValueError('input_shape: ', input_shape, 'and input_tensor: ',
                           input_tensor,
                           'do not meet the same shape requirements')
      else:
        if backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[2] != input_shape[1]:
          raise ValueError('input_shape: ', input_shape, 'and input_tensor: ',
                           input_tensor,
                           'do not meet the same shape requirements')
    else:
      raise ValueError('input_tensor specified: ', input_tensor,
                       'is not a keras tensor')

  # If input_shape is None, infer shape from input_tensor
  if input_shape is None and input_tensor is not None:

    try:
      backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor)
    except ValueError:
      raise ValueError('input_tensor: ', input_tensor, 'is type: ',
                       type(input_tensor), 'which is not a valid type')

    if input_shape is None and not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
      default_size = 224
    elif input_shape is None and backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
      if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
        rows = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[2]
        cols = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[3]
      else:
        rows = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[1]
        cols = backend.int_shape(input_tensor)[2]

      if rows == cols and rows in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]:
        default_size = rows
      else:
        default_size = 224

  # If input_shape is None and no input_tensor
  elif input_shape is None:
    default_size = 224

  # If input_shape is not None, assume default size
  else:
    if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
      rows = input_shape[1]
      cols = input_shape[2]
    else:
      rows = input_shape[0]
      cols = input_shape[1]

    if rows == cols and rows in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]:
      default_size = rows
    else:
      default_size = 224

  input_shape = imagenet_utils.obtain_input_shape(
      input_shape,
      default_size=default_size,
      min_size=32,
      data_format=backend.image_data_format(),
      require_flatten=include_top,
      weights=weights)

  if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    row_axis, col_axis = (0, 1)
  else:
    row_axis, col_axis = (1, 2)
  rows = input_shape[row_axis]
  cols = input_shape[col_axis]

  if weights == 'imagenet':
    if alpha not in [0.35, 0.50, 0.75, 1.0, 1.3, 1.4]:
      raise ValueError('If imagenet weights are being loaded, '
                       'alpha can be one of `0.35`, `0.50`, `0.75`, '
                       '`1.0`, `1.3` or `1.4` only.')

    if rows != cols or rows not in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224]:
      rows = 224
      logging.warning('`input_shape` is undefined or non-square, '
                      'or `rows` is not in [96, 128, 160, 192, 224].'
                      ' Weights for input shape (224, 224) will be'
                      ' loaded as the default.')

  if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
  else:
    if not backend.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
      img_input = layers.Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    else:
      img_input = input_tensor

  channel_axis = 1 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1

  first_block_filters = _make_divisible(32 * alpha, 8)
  x = layers.Conv2D(
      first_block_filters,
      kernel_size=3,
      strides=(2, 2),
      padding='same',
      use_bias=False,
      name='Conv1')(img_input)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name='bn_Conv1')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name='Conv1_relu')(x)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=16, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=1, block_id=0)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=1)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=24, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=2)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=3)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=4)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=32, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=5)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=6)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=7)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=8)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=64, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=9)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=10)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=11)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=96, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=12)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=2, expansion=6, block_id=13)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=14)
  ########################################################################################
  #x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=160, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=15)
  """Inverted ResNet block."""
  inputs=x
  filters=160
  alpha=alpha
  stride=1
  expansion=6
  block_id=15
  channel_axis = 1 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
  in_channels = backend.int_shape(inputs)[channel_axis]
  pointwise_conv_filters = int(filters * alpha)
  pointwise_filters = _make_divisible(pointwise_conv_filters, 8)
  x = inputs
  prefix = 'block_{}_'.format(block_id)
  x = _inverted_res_block(x, filters=320, alpha=alpha, stride=1, expansion=6, block_id=16)
  if alpha > 1.0:
    last_block_filters = _make_divisible(1280 * alpha, 8)
  else:
    last_block_filters = 1280
  x = layers.Conv2D(last_block_filters, kernel_size=1, use_bias=False, name='Conv_1')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis, epsilon=1e-3, momentum=0.999, name='Conv_1_bn')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name='out_relu')(x)
  if include_top:
    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    imagenet_utils.validate_activation(classifier_activation, weights)
    x = layers.Dense(classes, activation=classifier_activation,name='predictions')(x)
  else:
    if pooling == 'avg':
      x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
    elif pooling == 'max':
      x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
  if input_tensor is not None:
    inputs = layer_utils.get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
  else:
    inputs = img_input
  # Create model.
  model = training.Model(inputs, x, name='mobilenetv2_%0.2f_%s' % (alpha, rows))
  # Load weights.
   ##############################
   Code modification and loading pretrained weights
  #################################################
  if weights == 'imagenet':
    if include_top:
      model_pretrained = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
      input_shape=None, alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
      input_tensor=None, pooling=None, classes=2,
      classifier_activation='softmax')
      for i in range(0,134):
        model.layers[i].set_weights(model_pretrained.layers[i].get_weights())
  ### Block 16 pretrained weights assignment.
      for i,j in zip(range(134,147),range(143,154)):
        model.layers[i].set_weights(model_pretrained.layers[j].get_weights()) 
  #elif weights is not None:
    #model.load_weights(weights)   
  return model
  #############################
def _inverted_res_block(inputs, expansion, stride, alpha, filters, block_id):
  """Inverted ResNet block."""
  channel_axis = 1 if backend.image_data_format() == 'channels_first' else -1
  in_channels = backend.int_shape(inputs)[channel_axis]
  pointwise_conv_filters = int(filters * alpha)
  pointwise_filters = _make_divisible(pointwise_conv_filters, 8)
  x = inputs
  prefix = 'block_{}_'.format(block_id)
  if block_id:
    x = layers.Conv2D(expansion * in_channels,kernel_size=1,padding='same',use_bias=False,activation=None,name=prefix + 'expand')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'expand_BN')(x)
    x = layers.ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'expand_relu')(x)
  else:
    prefix = 'expanded_conv_'
  if stride == 2:
    x = layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=imagenet_utils.correct_pad(x, 3),name=prefix + 'pad')(x)
  x = layers.DepthwiseConv2D( kernel_size=3,strides=stride,activation=None,use_bias=False,padding='same' if stride == 1 else 'valid',name=prefix + 'depthwise')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'depthwise_BN')(x)
  x = layers.ReLU(6., name=prefix + 'depthwise_relu')(x)
  x = layers.Conv2D(pointwise_filters,kernel_size=1,padding='same',use_bias=False,activation=None,name=prefix + 'project')(x)
  x = layers.BatchNormalization(axis=channel_axis,epsilon=1e-3,momentum=0.999,name=prefix + 'project_BN')(x)
  if in_channels == pointwise_filters and stride == 1:
    return layers.Add(name=prefix + 'add')([inputs, x])
  return x

def _make_divisible(v, divisor, min_value=None):
  if min_value is None:
    min_value = divisor
  new_v = max(min_value, int(v + divisor / 2) // divisor * divisor)
  # Make sure that round down does not go down by more than 10%.
  if new_v < 0.9 * v:
    new_v += divisor
  return new_v
@keras_export('keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input')
def preprocess_input(x, data_format=None):
  return imagenet_utils.preprocess_input(x, data_format=data_format, mode='tf')
@keras_export('keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.decode_predictions')
def decode_predictions(preds, top=5):
  return imagenet_utils.decode_predictions(preds, top=top)
preprocess_input.__doc__ = imagenet_utils.PREPROCESS_INPUT_DOC.format(mode='',ret=imagenet_utils.PREPROCESS_INPUT_RET_DOC_TF,error=imagenet_utils.PREPROCESS_INPUT_ERROR_DOC)
decode_predictions.__doc__ = imagenet_utils.decode_predictions.__doc__
```

But the issue is this,  I need the classification for two class therefore I changed the code to `include_top=False` in the original model like this

```
if weights == 'imagenet':
    if include_top:
      model_pretrained = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
      input_shape=None, alpha=1.0, include_top=False, weights='imagenet',
      input_tensor=None, pooling=None, classes=2,
      classifier_activation='softmax'
    )
```

I then called the customised model using below code, however, I am still getting model with 1000 classes.

```
MobileNetV2_skip_15= MobileNetV2_15(input_shape=None,
                       alpha=1.0,
                       include_top=True,
                       weights='imagenet',     
                       input_tensor=None,
                       pooling=None,
                       classes=1000,
                       classifier_activation='softmax')
MobileNetV2_skip_15.summary()
```

Comment: You are creating a variable model_pretrained but that variable is not returned by the function.